# Am I using "warnings" module right?

Tags: python, warnings

I am using this to issue warnings while parsing a configuration file. All sorts of errors could happen while doing this - some fatal, some not. All those non-fatal errors should not interrupt the parsing, but they must not escape user's attention either. This is where the warnings module comes in.

I am currently doing this (pseudo code):

```
while parsing:
    try:
        get dictionary["token"]
    except KeyError:
        warnings.warn("Looks like your config file don't have that token")
```

This all looks readable and cozy, but the message looks something like this:

```
C:\Users\Renae\Documents\test.py:3: UserWarning: Looks like your config file don't have that token
  warnings.warn("Looks like your config file don't have that token")
```

Why is it printed twice? Should I be doing some sort of initialization before issuing warnings (like the logging module)? The standard docs doesn't have a tutorial on this (or does it?).

What differentiates warnings from print(), stdout or stderr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using `warnings` module, the second print is actually the stack, you can control what level you want to print using the `stacklevel` argument. Example -

```
import warnings
def warn():
    warnings.warn("Blah",stacklevel=2)

warn()
```

This results -

```
a.py:6: UserWarning: Blah
  warn()
```

If you set it to a non-existent level , in the above example lets say `3` , then it does not print the stack, Example -

```
def warn():
    warnings.warn("Blah",stacklevel=3)
```

Result -

```
sys:1: UserWarning: Blah
```

Though as you can see, the file also changed to `sys:1` . You might want to show a meaning stack over there (maybe something like stacklevel=2 for the caller of the function in which the warning was raised) .

Another way to suppress this would be to use [`warnings.warn_explicit()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html#warnings.warn_explicit) method and manually pass in the filename and linenumber (linenumber should not have any actual code in it, otherwise that code would be printed), though I do not advice this.

---

Also, yes when using `warnings` module, the data normally goes into `sys.stderr` , but you can also easily send warnings to a different file by using different functions like - [`warnings.showwarning()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html#warnings.showwarning)